# why while(true) in java not working as i expected in thread

Tags: java, swing, while-loop, jframe, action

i'm doing a task using other jframe. At now, i have 2 jframes, at jframe1 when i click button add new. Next, jframe2 will display and i want to catch event from this jframe when click, so i use thread and while(true) but it not working as i expected, after i click add at jframe2, thread at jframe1 not catch and it still loop infinite. i debuged, it's work ok but when i run it's not work as when i debug. what wrong there? 
Here my code in jframe1:

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("add new");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Thread t = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("start");
                    Frame2 f2 = new Frame2();
                    do {
                        if (f2.getCheck() == 0) {
                            System.out.println("catched");
                            break;
                        }
                    } while (true);
                    System.out.println("end");
                };
            };
            t.start();
            
        }
    });
```

and here my code in jframe2:

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("add");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            check = 0;
            frame.dispose();
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the definition of the variable `check`? Does it have a `volatile` modifier?

Comment: You are creating a new `Frame2` object, which is not the one you clicked.

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. 3) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: I do not see any blocking of the EDT.  The loop is offloaded to a different thread and the EDT is freed.

Comment: @pveentjer *"I do not see any blocking of the EDT."* I don't see an MRE / SSCCE. I won't spend my time looking closely at code until there is one. As an aside, it seems a Swing based `Timer` might be best to achieve .. *whatever* it is the OP is trying to achieve with this code, and the (copy/paste comment) link I provided cover both `SwingWorker` and `Timer`. But hey, feel free to prove me wrong by solving the problem. I'll wait for the MRE / SSCCE before giving this more thought. 

Comment: @KevinO because answer of rzwitserloot, i solved my problem, i also read article that you mention but because here just a task for beginer as me, i thanks to everyone,  because i leaned new things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java Memory Model is to blame.

The JVM has an evil coin.

It will flip this coin sometimes. Specifically, anytime you access any field, the JVM flips the evil coin.

Heads, and the JVM will give you the value contained in this field that it has cached from earlier. The value that it had in this thread, regardless of any updates written to it from other threads.

Tails, and it will give you the value as it was written to last, by any thread.

It's evil, in the sense that it is not a fair coin: Today, and during your unit tests, and as the debugger runs, and with this particular phase of the moon, it works every time. Same tomorrow and next week. But 2 weeks from now just as you are giving that demo to the important customer? Reliably failing.

The key point is: **If you make the JVM ever flip the coin, you lost**.

Do not make the JVM flip it.

To disble the JVM's evil coin, you must establish so-called happens-before/happens-after relationships.

An HB/HA relationship works as follows:

- For any 2 statements anywhere in your entire code base, the 2 statements either have HB/HA, or they do not.
- If they do have HB/HA, then the JVM guarantees you that the happens-after line cannot observe any state as it was *before* the happens-before line, *other than timing*. In other words, code executes as if the statement that has the 'happens before' relationship with the 'happens after' line actually happened before. It doesn't actually have to, but you cannot observe that it didn't, so that doesn't matter.
- However, if they do not have HB/HA, anything can happen. You may observe it, or not, even if you have absolute proof that line B ran after line A, then line B may or may not observe anything A changed, JVM's discretion: Evil coin flips occur.

You may find this all incredibly stupid design and obviously bizarre; why would the JVM have an evil coin and why is it playing these games?

The answer is efficiency. Inter-core communication is incredibly expensive. The JVM will often but not always attempt to run code efficiently and this usually involves a local cached copy. The JVM doesn't spend every moment checking if it has nothing to do and aggressively synchronizing all these caches together in some sensible fashion, that would be *far* too inefficient. CPUs have other stuff to do, and even if they don't, hey, laptops are a thing, as is the power bill, as is your Datacenter's provisioned CPU cycle counts, so spending CPU cycles that aren't neccessary is a waste that shouldn't be occurring.

So the JVM doesn't. It will happily leave things unsynced, or not, at is discretion, for days if it wants.

**That** is what you are observing. With the debugger fired up, all sorts of efficiencies aren't run because they would confuse the debugger, so you are observing from thread A that `check = 0` many seconds after thread B set it to that value. But, without the debugger on, you may print something that tells you B has set `check` to 0, but then A sees that check isn't 0 for days on end.

In other words, in thread B, `check` seems to be 0. You can print the time and confirm that this happens at point in time X. And yet, even though it is **clearly** much, much later, A is *still* observing that `check` is still `3` or whatever it was before A set it to 0. The explanation is that B and A each have their own copy of `check`. The JVM isn't gonna sync em just cuz you want it to. And there is no simple `syncItUp()` method. And, yeah, there is no guarantee that these local copies are there either. The JVM is free to sync them up or not. With the debugger on, it syncs em. Without it, it doesn't. Weird, but the spec of the JVM gives the JVM the power to do it. Evil coin. The one, and only, way to guarantee things, is to establish HB/HA.

To establish HB/HA, well, you can search the web. But, the easy ways are:

- The `synchronized` keyword: If thread A exits a block that synchronized on object ref to object X, that is guaranteed to 'happen before' any other thread that enters such a synchronized block later on.
- Thread starts. If thread A starts thread B, then the line right before `b.start();` is HB relative to the first line in thread B.
- `volatile`. writes to volatile fields establish HB/HA vs. reads, though you get no guarantees if it actually runs earlier (these aren't locks). It would 'work' here in your case, though.
- Any java library tool that internally uses this stuff. For example, just about everything in the `java.util.concurrent` package.

So, in short, make that `volatile`. More generally though, trying to read and write to the same field from different threads is Here Be Dragons and They WILL bite your head off! territory. It's hard to write the code properly and if you mess up, a unit test won't catch it. You'll have a flakey app that works great for you and fails on other machines or in bizarre conditions.

If you can, use proper tools (j.u.c classes are a good start), and try to just not write to fields from multiple threads, at all. For example, do all inter-thread comms via a database with proper transaction management.

Comment: hasn't something with OP's issue, please read comment by Andrew Thompson, especially in the part about Concurrency in Swing, everything from code block `Thread t = new Thread()` simple disapears to ..., and nothing can by repainted.

Comment: @mKorbel actually it has everything to do with the OP's issue. Apparently `check` is not declared as `volatile` in class `Frame2`. If it is declared `volatile` then clicking the `add` button (in `Frame2`) prints _catched_ and _end_ to the standard output.

Comment: You can get a 100% evil coin of the JIT has optimized-out a read/write. Your story about caches being optionally in sync is incorrect. Modern CPU's have coherent caches. So even if all loads and stores are plain, CPU caches would still be coherent.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i solved my problem and leaned new things, thanks a lot